# string compare in Ruby not working

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I'm not sure what is going on here. I need to run a string compare on two variables that are Times. One variable is a Time object using the .mtime function. The other variable is taken from a sqlite3 database. I would like to compare these times to see if the modification date is different from the last modification date that is listed in the sqlite3 table. here is the code for that part.

When I print out the values they look identical...So why is the compare not working

```
def scanfile
  dir = Dir.new(Dir.pwd)
  dir.each do |file|
    fileName = File.basename(file)
    modTime = File.mtime(file).strftime("%F %T")
    lastMod = nil
    exists = checkDB(fileName)
    if exists == true
      $db.execute("SELECT DateMod FROM Files WHERE fileName = '#{fileName}'") do |mod|
        lastMod = mod
      end
      mod = modTime.to_s

      printf("modTime: #{mod} lastMod: #{lastMod}\n")
      if mod != lastMod
        $db.execute("UPDATE Files SET NumMods=NumMods+1 WHERE fileName = '#{fileName}'")
        $db.execute("UPDATE Files SET DateMod='#{modTime}' WHERE fileName = '#{fileName}'")
        print "#{fileName} updated...\n"
      end
    else
      if fileName != "." && fileName != ".."    
        inputRecord(fileName, modTime, modTime, 1)
        print "#{fileName} inserted...\n"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There's a couple things you could do to save yourself a lot of work. First, use an ORM, like Sequel, Datamapper or ActiveRecord to abstract your database connection. The value in that is your date, date time and time fields will be abstracted so you can do simple Date, DateTime or Time math on them. Another major benefit is converting to different DBMs will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

When you use [`execute`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sqlite-ruby/2.1.0/SQLite/Database%3aexecute) (or [this version](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sqlite3-ruby/1.2.5/SQLite3/Database%3aexecute)), you'll be working with the result set's rows as arrays of strings, not simple strings. So in here:

```
$db.execute(...) do |mod|
  #...
end
```

your `mod` will be an array which contains a single string. The problem is that you're saving that array and treating it like a string; with sufficient `to_s` calls and similar mangling, you'll get a string that looks right to both you and Ruby and everything will work.

You should unpack the row array yourself:

```
$db.execute(...) do |mod|
  lastMod = mod.first
  # ------------^^^^^
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out. I am not sure why this fixed it because I thought I was basically doing this but using:

```
if !modTime.to_s.eql? lastMod.to_s
```

worked out well..